# How do i serialize a generic sealed class with kotlinx.serialization

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.serialization, sealed-class

Not sure if it is possible yet but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to serialize this.

```
sealed class ServiceResult<out T : Any> {
    data class Success<out T : Any>(val data: T) : ServiceResult<T>()
    data class Error(val exception: Exception) : ServiceResult<Nothing>()
}
```

Everything that is stuff into T is using @Serializable ex:

```
@Serializable
data class GalleryDTO(
    override val id: Int,
    override val dateCreated: Long,
    override val dateUpdated: Long,
    val name:String,
    val description:String,
    val photos:List<DTOMin>
) : DTO
```

Comment: Related: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/944

Comment: You want to serialize errors too?

Comment: I can live with Error just carrying a string. Kinda want a nice and clean way to digest my rest data client side.

Comment: Do you need deserialization too?

Answer (score 3):

As [Animesh Sahu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64826750/how-do-i-serialize-a-generic-sealed-class-with-kotlinx-serialization#comment114633132_64826750) already mentioned there is an issue for this topic that is still open, but the solution using a surrogate suggested by [Михаил Нафталь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64826750/how-do-i-serialize-a-generic-sealed-class-with-kotlinx-serialization/64896796#64896796) for serialization of `Error` can actually be used also to serialize the polymorphic `ServiceResult`, by creating a surrogate that mixes the fields of `Success` and `Error`. For the sake of simplicity in the example I only represent the exception message.

```kotlin
@Serializable(with = ServiceResultSerializer::class)
sealed class ServiceResult<out T : Any> {
    data class Success<out T : Any>(val data: T) : ServiceResult<T>()
    data class Error(val exceptionMessage: String?) : ServiceResult<Nothing>()
}

class ServiceResultSerializer<T : Any>(
    tSerializer: KSerializer<T>
) : KSerializer<ServiceResult<T>> {
    @Serializable
    @SerialName("ServiceResult")
    data class ServiceResultSurrogate<T : Any>(
        val type: Type,
        // The annotation is not necessary, but it avoids serializing "data = null" 
        // for "Error" results.
        @EncodeDefault(EncodeDefault.Mode.NEVER)
        val data: T? = null,
        @EncodeDefault(EncodeDefault.Mode.NEVER)
        val exceptionMessage: String? = null
    ) {
        enum class Type { SUCCESS, ERROR }
    }

    private val surrogateSerializer = ServiceResultSurrogate.serializer(tSerializer)

    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = surrogateSerializer.descriptor

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): ServiceResult<T> {
        val surrogate = surrogateSerializer.deserialize(decoder)
        return when (surrogate.type) {
            ServiceResultSurrogate.Type.SUCCESS ->
                if (surrogate.data != null)
                    ServiceResult.Success(surrogate.data)
                else
                    throw SerializationException("Missing data for successful result")
            ServiceResultSurrogate.Type.ERROR ->
                ServiceResult.Error(surrogate.exceptionMessage)
        }
    }

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: ServiceResult<T>) {
        val surrogate = when (value) {
            is ServiceResult.Error -> ServiceResultSurrogate(
                ServiceResultSurrogate.Type.ERROR,
                exceptionMessage = value.exceptionMessage
            )
            is ServiceResult.Success -> ServiceResultSurrogate(
                ServiceResultSurrogate.Type.SUCCESS,
                data = value.data
            )
        }
        surrogateSerializer.serialize(encoder, surrogate)
    }
}
```

This solution can also be easily extended to support nullable `T`s. In this case when deserializing you will also have to check if `null` is a valid value for `T` (it can be done by checking `descriptor.isNullable` on `tSerializer`) and you will also have to cast `data as T`.

Answer (score 0):

[Polymorphic serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/polymorphism.md) will be a mess in this case (you will have to manually register all possible types passed as a generic parameter to `ServiceResult<T>`), and will have several limitations (it would be impossible to register primitive types (including `Nothing` and `String`) as generic parameters, for instance).
If you only need serialization (aka encoding), I'd recommend to serialize both subtypes independently (for convenience, wrap subtype determination into auxilary function):

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T : Any> serializeServiceResult(x: ServiceResult<T>) = when (x) {
    is ServiceResult.Success -> Json.encodeToString(x)
    is ServiceResult.Error -> Json.encodeToString(x)
}
```

To serialize `ServiceResult.Success` you need just to mark it with `@Serializable` annotation. The tricky part here is serialization of `ServiceResult.Error`, or more precisely, serialization of its `exception: Exception` field. I'd suggest to serialize only its message (via [surrogate](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/serializers.md#composite-serializer-via-surrogate)):

```kotlin
sealed class ServiceResult<out T : Any> {
    @Serializable
    data class Success<out T : Any>(val data: T) : ServiceResult<T>()

    @Serializable(with = ErrorSerializer::class)
    data class Error(val exception: Exception) : ServiceResult<Nothing>()
}

@Serializable
private data class ErrorSurrogate(val error: String)

class ErrorSerializer : KSerializer<ServiceResult.Error> {
    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = ErrorSurrogate.serializer().descriptor

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): ServiceResult.Error {
        val surrogate = decoder.decodeSerializableValue(ErrorSurrogate.serializer())
        return ServiceResult.Error(Exception(surrogate.error))
    }

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: ServiceResult.Error) {
        val surrogate = ErrorSurrogate(value.exception.toString())
        encoder.encodeSerializableValue(ErrorSurrogate.serializer(), surrogate)
    }
}
```